# Data classification in buckets

Tags: r, pivot

I have a data frame named as Data which has the following elements:

```
Model  Garage  City  Unit.Price Invoice.Date  Components    
Hyundai  A      NY     500        31/12/2016   HL   
Honda    B      NJ     700        31/12/2016   TL     
Porsche  A      NY     800        30/12/2016   TL    
BMW      B      NJ     800        30/12/2016   HL   
BMW      A      NJ     700        31/12/2016   HL   
Porsche  B      NY     800        30/12/2016   TL   
Honda    A      NY     400        30/12/2016   TL  
Honda    A      NY     500        30/12/2016   HL  
Honda    B      NY     600        30/12/2016   HL  
Honda    A      NY     200        29/12/2016   TL  
Honda    A      NY     300        29/12/2016   HL
```

I want the output of Data broken into cars sorted with `Invoice.Date` so that the current cost is captured first.

```
Ex:Honda

Components    GarageA   GarageB    
HL             500          600    
TL             400          700
```

This is how I started:

```
Category <- as.data.frame(c("BMW","Honda","Porsche","Hyundai"))

for(i in 1:nrow(Category))
{
  m <- Category[i,1]
  X <- subset(Data,Model==m)
  X <- Data[order(Data$Invoice.Date,decreasing = T),]
  Pivot_A<-dcast(X,Name~Garage,value.var = "Unit.Price",function(x) length((x)))
  write.csv(Pivot,file = paste(X,"Cars.csv",sep = "_"))
 }
```

The only issue I am getting is to map the correct unit price. Is there any code or function to do this with `dcast`? `dcast` has options of `sum`, `count`. What If I want the exact amount and not `sum`, `average`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `order` the rows by the 'Invoice.Date' and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' with `dcast` while specifying the `fun.aggregate` to select only the first observation

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dcast(setDT(df1)[order(dmy(Invoice.Date))] , Model + Components ~ 
  paste0("Garage", Garage), value.var = "Unit.Price", function(x) x[1])
#     Model Components GarageA GarageB
#1:     BMW         HL     700     800
#2:   Honda         HL     300     600
#3:   Honda         TL     200     700
#4: Hyundai         HL     500      NA
#5: Porsche         TL     800     800
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by:

```
require(tidyverse) # dplyr would be enough...
dat %>% 
  mutate(Invoice.Date = as.Date(Invoice.Date, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  group_by(Model, Garage, Components) %>% 
  summarise(Unit.Price = first(Unit.Price, order_by = Invoice.Date)) %>% 
  spread(Garage, Unit.Price, sep = "")
```

Which gives you:

```
    Model Components GarageA GarageB
*   <chr>      <chr>   <int>   <int>
1     BMW         HL     700     800
2   Honda         HL     300     600
3   Honda         TL     200     700
4 Hyundai         HL     500      NA
5 Porsche         TL     800     800
```

Now i am not sure how to interpret the **broken into cars** in your question. You could pipe (`%>%`) the above into

- `split(.$Model)` to get a list where each list-element represents one *Model*.
- `nest(-Model)` to get a nested tibble...

Answer (score 0):

And consider R's best package, `base`:

```
library(base)  # COMPLETELY REDUNDANT =)

df <- df[with(df, order(Invoice.Date)),]
dfagg <- aggregate(Unit.Price ~ Model + Components + Garage, df, function(i) tail(i)[1])
dfwide <- reshape(dfagg, timevar='Garage', idvar=c('Model', 'Components'), direction="wide")
names(dfwide) <- gsub("Unit.Price.", "Garage", names(dfwide))

#     Model Components GarageA GarageB
# 1     BMW         HL     700     800
# 2   Honda         HL     300     600
# 3 Hyundai         HL     500      NA
# 4   Honda         TL     200     700
# 5 Porsche         TL     800     800
```